# what you do to keep user logged in in react native app

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

As of now I am storing token in async-storage. and then checking that in splash screen API. so If available then user can direct navigate to Home if not then user navigate to login screen or sign up screen. I know that this is not good way if we talk about security. then please tell me what is best way to do this, what you guys do

Comment: "I know this is not good way if we talk about security", sorry do you mind to elaborate like how you know? from which aspect?

Comment: means someone can access user mobile data by rooting mobile

Comment: you can make use of `keychain` for iOS and `keystore` for Android, check `react-native-keychain`.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keychain

Comment: keeps a shorter timespan of your token, when you first launch the app, check validity of token and if expired, call a refresh token. Everything should be behind the scene and your user should not be able to notice that

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is not a solution for that. On rooted devices you can access keychain and shared-preferences. But if this situation is important you can make shorter token time.